# Driving distance area

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way, via the Google Maps API, to determine the bounding polygon within a given driving time of a given central point?

Failing that, is there a way to calculate the inverse of the driving time function -- that is, instead of "how many minutes does it take to get from point A to point B", a way to ask "how far will I get from point A to point B in a certain number of minutes?" Of course I could just find the time between points and assume naive scaling, but that could be way off if the speed limits vary widely over significant portions of the route.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for an [isochrone map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochrone_map)

- [Marcelo's original driving radius demo](http://www.geocodezip.com/v2_marcelo_driveTimePolygon.html) original link is now dead.
- [Marcelo's driving radius demo ported to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_marcelo_driveTimePolygon.html)

**Note:** these examples no longer work due to Google's policy change (`You have exceeded your request quota for this API.` error), replace the API key with an active one and they will work)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var container;
var zoom = 9;
var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(35.149534, -90.04898);
var dirService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var centerMarker;
var circleMarkers = Array();
var circlePoints = Array();
var drivePolyPoints = Array();
var searchPolygon, drivePolygon;
var distToDrive = 30; // miles
var pointInterval = 30;
var searchPoints = [];
var polyline;
var polylines = [];
var redIcon8 = "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png";

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: centerPoint,
      zoom: 9,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", mapClick);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function mapClick(evt) {
  // map.clearOverlays();
  circleMarkers = Array();
  if (!centerMarker) {
    centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: evt.latLng,
      map: map
    });
  } else {
    centerMarker.setMap(null);
    centerMarker.setPosition(evt.latLng);
  }
  centerMarker.setMap(map);
  searchPoints = getCirclePoints(evt.latLng, distToDrive);
  drivePolyPoints = Array();
  getDirections();
}

function getCirclePoints(center, radius) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var circlePoints = Array();
  var searchPoints = Array();
  with(Math) {
    var rLat = (radius / 3963.189) * (180 / PI); // miles
    var rLng = rLat / cos(center.lat() * (PI / 180));
    for (var a = 0; a < 361; a++) {
      var aRad = a * (PI / 180);
      var x = center.lng() + (rLng * cos(aRad));
      var y = center.lat() + (rLat * sin(aRad));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(y), parseFloat(x), true);
      bounds.extend(point);
      circlePoints.push(point);
      if (a % pointInterval == 0) {
        searchPoints.push(point);
      }
    }
  }
  searchPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: circlePoints,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.2
  });
  searchPolygon.setMap(map);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  return searchPoints;
}

function getDirections() {
  if (!searchPoints.length) {
    return;
  }
  var to = searchPoints.shift();
  var request = {
    origin: centerMarker.getPosition(),
    destination: to,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  dirService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var distance = parseInt(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609);
      var duration = parseFloat(result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 3600).toFixed(2);
      var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
      var legs = result.routes[0].legs;
      if (polyline && polyline.setPath) {
        polyline.setPath([]);
      } else {
        polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [],
          // map: map,
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 1
        });
      }
      for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
        var steps = legs[i].steps;
        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
          for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
            polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            // bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
          }
        }
      }
      // polyline.setMap(map);
      shortenAndShow(polyline);
      getDirections();
    } else {
      console.log("Directions request failed, status=" + status + " [from:" + request.origin + " to:" + request.destination + "]");
      getDirections();
    }
  });
}

function shortenAndShow(polyline) {
  var distToDriveM = distToDrive * 1609;
  var dist = 0;
  var cutoffIndex = 0;
  var copyPoints = Array();
  for (var n = 0; n < polyline.getPath().getLength() - 1; n++) {
    dist += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(polyline.getPath().getAt(n), polyline.getPath().getAt(n + 1));
    //GLog.write(dist + ' - ' + distToDriveM);
    if (dist < distToDriveM) {
      copyPoints.push(polyline.getPath().getAt(n));
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  var lastPoint = copyPoints[copyPoints.length - 1];
  var newLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: copyPoints,
    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 1
  });
  newLine.setMap(map);
  polylines.push(newLine);
  drivePolyPoints.push(lastPoint);
  addBorderMarker(lastPoint, dist)
  if (drivePolyPoints.length > 3) {
    if (drivePolygon) {
      drivePolygon.setMap(null);
    }
    drivePolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: drivePolyPoints,
      strokeColor: '#00ff00',
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      fillColor: '#00ff00',
      fillOpacity: 0.4
    });
    drivePolygon.setMap(map);
  }
}

function addBorderMarker(pt, d) {
  var str = pt.lat().toFixed(6) + ',' + pt.lng().toFixed(6) + ' - Driving Distance: ' + (d / 1609).toFixed(2) + ' miles';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pt,
    icon: redIcon8,
    title: str
  });
  circleMarkers.push(marker);
  marker.setMap(map);
}

function clearOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < circleMarkers.length; i++) {
    circleMarkers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  circleMarkers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < circlePoints.length; i++) {
    circlePoints[i].setMap(null);
  }
  circlePoints = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
    polylines[i].setMap(null);
  }
  polylines = [];
  if (searchPolygon && searchPolygon.setMap) searchPolygon.setMap(null);
  if (drivePolygon && drivePolygon.setMap) drivePolygon.setMap(null);
  if (centerMarker && centerMarker.setMap) centerMarker.setMap(null);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="clearOverlays();">Clear</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="pointInterval=30;clearOverlays();">interval 30 (default)</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="pointInterval=20;clearOverlays();">interval 20</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made [**this driving radius demo**](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_driving_radius.html) some years ago, but it uses the API V2, which is now deprecated. You'd only need to convert it to V3.

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score -1):

i know this question has been 8 years ago, but it is very helpful, here is the fiddle link for the demo, because all the links above are not working.
[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/12168/)

you just have to change API KEY with your own and also i have changed the unit from mile to kilometer.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}"></script>
```

Comment: Did you make any changes?  Your fiddle doesn't work either, I'm not sure what value another link to  a non-working example is (the problem with my examples is the key, replace that with an active key, and they will work, as I assume you discovered)

Comment: yes i just changed the unit from mile to km, i just copy paste  the code and use my api key