# Google Maps -> Making a circular route based on given distance?

Tags: google-maps

Trying to avoid reinventing the wheel here.

Anyone knows of any API that lets one create a route that starts and ends at the user's position, given as parameter the distance required for the route?

For example, you want to take a walk. A walk of a total of 5KM from home and back to home. Any API that will work with Google Maps to offer routes?

Thanks, as always.

Comment: possibly related question: [Driving distance area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317990/driving-distance-area)

Comment: Did you find any solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with the use of [Google Maps API Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) which receives direction requests and returns computed results.

Furthermore, with this API, you can create a route that starts and ends at the user's position by [Using Waypoints in Routes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) .

As mentioned,

> Travel time is the primary factor which is optimized, but other factors such as **distance, number of turns and many more may be taken into account when deciding which route is the most efficient**.

Please note, however, that the use of Directions service must be in accordance with the [policies described for the Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/policies).

Comment: How can it be made sure that the total route distance is 5 KM as per the question?