# Find cities within one hour from my location

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I want to use some Google API to find a list of places within one hour from my location. I've found **Google Maps Distance Matrix API** but it only gives you the distance between places you specify.

What I really want to do is to paint an area in a map, I don't really need the list of places.

If I can't query by time maybe I can deal with distance (which is probably easier)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Driving distance area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317990/driving-distance-area)

Comment: What you are looking for is a so called Isochrone calculation, where there are different API providers out there